# how to distinguish local and global server

Tags: php, localhost

How do i know that this is global or local environment for my php pages

means i m using Google map Key
 there is two different key  one for local server and another for that domain where it has to be shown, so how do i write the code  for both keys together and page automaticaaly detect that which key have to be  use

these things i also want to apply for config files 
i want that when site is on the web server , config files take username and password of that server otherwise take local user and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost")
{
    define("LOCAL_ENV", true);
}
else
{
    define("LOCAL_ENV", false);
}
```

Then just check whether it is true or false.

Another option is to simply use separate config files, so the config.php on the server is

```
define("LOCAL_ENV", false);
```

and the config.php on localhost is

```
define("LOCAL_ENV", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can usually find out using

```
$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]
```

check out `phpinfo()` and the SERVER section there for a complete list of server side variables, including the current working directory (which is also a pretty good indicator of which server you are working on).

What I like to do is to set up a different config file for each server:

```
setup.localhost.php
setup.example.com.php
```

That way, I don't have to switch anything. 
You should just turn that off for production use, as `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` could probably be faked under some virtual host settings.